# How can I build a market on Android?

Tags: kingdoms-of-camelot

I know that on Facebook you can trade resources for gold but it seems that I can't find the marking on Android so I could initiate trades with my resources.

Can we trade on Android version of the game, if so how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no market in the mobile version of the game.  I would suggest joining an alliance to trade your resources.  Coordinate with other users with each others locations and come to an agreement for how much resources to trade.  Please be advised that there is no secure trading system, so be careful who you trade with.